# Toggle Isolate script not updating

Tags: python, maya

I've written a script that toggles the active viewports 'isolate selected' feature. How come this doesn't seem to isolate the selected objects? My approach seems correct but i'm missing something somewhere and I can't seem to locate what exactly it is.

```
import maya.cmds as cmds

viewports = cmds.getPanel( type='modelPanel' )
curPanel = cmds.getPanel( withFocus=True )

if curPanel in viewports:
    curState = cmds.isolateSelect( curPanel, q=True, state=True )
    notState = not curState

    if notState:
        cmds.isolateSelect( curPanel, addSelected=True)

    cmds.isolateSelect( curPanel, state=notState)
```

FIXED:

```
import maya.cmds as mc 
import maya.mel as mel

isoPnl = mc.getPanel(wf=True)
isoCrnt = mc.isolateSelect(isoPnl, q=True, s=True)
mel.eval('enableIsolateSelect %s %d' % (isoPnl,not isoCrnt) )
```

Comment: This doesn't run correctly for me at all. I made 5 spheres in the viewport. I selected 3 of them and ran the script....it resulted in an empty viewport. Where as it should have yielded a viewport with the 3 selected spheres....

Answer (score 0):

Your code is correctly *toggling* the isolate view on and off, but is doing nothing to *add* selected objects to that view, which is why it gives you an empty viewport.

To add selected objects, the command is:

```
cmds.isolateSelect(modelPanel, addSelected=True)
```

Probably the most logical would be to run that command when `notState` is true:

```
if curPanel in viewports:
    curState = cmds.isolateSelect( curPanel, q=True, state=True )
    notState = not curState

    cmds.isolateSelect( curPanel, state=notState)

    if notState:
        cmds.isolateSelect(modelPanel, addSelected=True)
```

Comment: When i run that script nothing is in the isolate viewport. It results in an empty viewport even though i had objects selected previously.
I'm not sure what I'm missing here but it doesn't seem to work as expected. I updated the code above with the changes you suggested.

Comment: I'll be in the office in about 30 minutes to test. Can you try putting the last line above the if statement and tell me if that works?

Comment: ok, you have to set the state, *then* add selected. edited answer and tested

Comment: This is surprisingly a bit more complex than i expected. I initially thought it would be a simple 'execute and watch listener and then convert to code'. I found that if you have previously isolated objects using the 'viewports' isolate button, and then run the code we have, it wont isolate just the selected, it will add to the previously isolated. Even if the viewport is no longer in the active 'isolated state'

Comment: i think you need to better define what exactly you want to happen. the code works for me for my understanding of what it should do

Comment: I simple just want to make a toggle for the 'isolate selected button' in maya. That way I can assign it to a key command rather than clicking the little icon in the viewport.